# Routes in Mean.JS

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, meanjs

I have a case where I need to expose the following server routes:

/cats/:catId
/cats?name=:name

How should my server routes look?  I tired this:

```
app.route('/cats/:catId')
        .get(cats.read)

app.route('/cats?name=:name')
        .get(cats.getByName)
```

But that doesn't work.  I seem to get routed to /cats in that case.

Should I have a route like this, or should I just do a switch in my server controller to handle the query strings as appropriate?

Comment: You can define second route simply as /cats and get query params from req.query.

Answer (score 3):

you are getting into a route conflict, you are doing a fallback into the first route you are defining with the string **cats**, I'd would suggest to change the pattern if possible, to avoid it, follow a [restful naming convention](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restfulresourcenaming.html), it could be the case of:

```
app.route('/cats/id/:catId').get(cats.read)
app.route('/cats/name/:name').get(cats.getByName)
```

does that makes sense?